# Not getting the WINDOW on using PYQT4 in ubuntu16

Tags: pyqt4, ubuntu-16.04

Here is my simple code to make a window using **pyqt4** , but after running the code gets compiled but not showing any window.

```
import sys  
import time

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QWidget()

window.show()
```

If there is some error in the code please correct me .

Comment: `app.exec_()`...

Comment: Yes it worked.What is the reason behind using this class?

Comment: It's all explained in the docs: [QApplication](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#details).